# How to change table cell background color based on cell value in using directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that displays data for health insurance allocation to a beneficiary. I need to add a condition that checks for values whose usage by a a member is more than 70% of the initial allocation and in such a scenario, the cell displaying that value background changes on mouse hover.

So  far, I have only been able to fetch all data from my back-end service and render it on the table.

My code implementation is as follows:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive input-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="th"><b>HEALTH BASKET</b></div>
          </th>
          <th >
            <div class="th"><b>ALLOCATION</b></div>
          </th>
          <th >
            <div class="th"><b>USAGE</b></div>
          </th>
          <th >
            <div class="th"><b>BALANCE</b></div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="voucher in vouchers">
          <td>{{voucher.voucherName}}</td>
          <td>{{voucher.value}}</td>
          <td >{{voucher.used}}</td>
          <td>{{voucher.amountRemaining}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea of how this can be implemented using the Angular directives?

Comment: Have you read about `ngClass`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the directives `ng-mouseover`, `ng-mouseleave` and `ng-class`

In your `<tbody>`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="voucher in vouchers" ng-class="{'usage-exceeded': usageExceeded}" ng-mouseover="checkUsage(voucher)" ng-mouseleave="usageExceeded = false">
        <td>{{voucher.voucherName}}</td>
        <td>{{voucher.value}}</td>
        <td >{{voucher.used}}</td>
        <td>{{voucher.amountRemaining}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And inside the controller function:

```
$scope.checkUsage = function (voucher) {
    // add the logic to set the $scope.usageExceeded as true, change this logic as per
    // your condition
    if ((voucher.used / voucher.value) * 100 > 70) {
        $scope.usageExceeded = true;
    }
};
```

Now, add the css class `usage-exceeded` inside your css which will change the background color.

```
.usage-exceeded {
    background-color: red;
}
```